# Read the content of directory in php

Tags: php, image, file, colors, imagefilter

please i am beginner in php and i want to read images in a folder
I have pictures with names like:

```
image_1_0_0_0.png
image_1_1_0_0.png
image_1_1_1_0.png
.........
.....
image_2_0_0_0.png
image_2_1_0_0.png

image_3_0_0_0.png
```

I want to assign a color (imagefilter) to the images that starts with image_1 _..... and another color for image_2 _... and another color to images_3 ....

then I want to read only the last image and retrieve only the number 3, the first number left

I want to know how to do this please.

Comment: and what you've tried yourself please ?

Comment: yes , I can browse the folder and assign a color to all images ,but i can't assign color1 to images begin with image_1 and color2 to images begin with image_2 ....

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: yes , I can browse the folder and assign a color to all images ,but i can't assign color1 to images begin with image_1 and color2 to images begin with image_2 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the content of a directory:

```
$dir = "/images/";
$color = "#000000";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      echo "Filename: ".$file."<br>";
      if($file[7]=='1') $color="#FF0000";
      elseif ($file[7]=='2') $color="#00FF00";
      elseif ($file[7]=='3') $color="#0000FF";
      else $color="#000000";
      // do something with the image
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

I don't understand your last question.

Comment: my last question is this:

in my folder I have images that starts with image_1_0_0 ..... up to image_3_0_0 ...., 
I want only retrieve the first number $file [7] of the last image in my folder in this exemple is 3

if i have images between image_1_0_0 ......up to image_4._0_0  i want to retreive only 4

Comment: In your loop, you can do something like $myMax = max($myMax, $file[7]). But this functions only with 1 digit numbers (0 to 9)